# How to get name of user by using user id in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I added a new user custom field on the Form, "Report manager", I can get the user id, but how to get user full name by using user id?

I need to add the code in view.detail.php & view.edit.php under Contact Module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from http://technology.ohmygoh.com/how-to-get-full-name-of-user-by-using-user-id-in-sugarcrm/

```
$myUser = new User();
$myUser->retrieve("YOUR-USER-ID");
$myUser->full_name;
```

But how to assign the full name value and display in Detail/Edit View instead of showing the user ID?